# How to get R# not to reformat ASP.NET MVC Spaghetti code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resharper

When I'm writing spaghetti code in my MVC views, R# keeps automatically dropping my braces to the next line and indenting and such. Is there a way I can turn this off for just my view pages?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this.  All R# formatting setting are system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris says in the comment, it can't be done.